# ORACLE: compare two vales PL/SQL

Tags: oracle

Hi i have the following script

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DOUBLE_BOOKINGS
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON BOOKING_SESSION
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    session_date TIMESTAMP;
    session_room NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT start_session
        INTO session_date --- EXISTING SESSION
        FROM booking_session
    WHERE bk_room = :NEW.bk_room;
    IF session_date = :NEW.start_session THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR
    (-1000, 'Room is already booked');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

The script is suppose to match any new bookings with the already existing bookings for the same room and same date (to stop double bookings)

However it isn't working correctly.

```
SQL> INSERT INTO BOOKING_SESSION VALUES (45,TO_TIMESTAMP('18/03/2012 10:00', '
INSERT INTO BOOKING_SESSION VALUES (45,TO_TIMESTAMP('18/03/2012 10:00', 'DD/MM
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04098: trigger 'U1146815.ROOM_BOOKED' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

The `start_session` is the database column name where i store the date and time of bookings and is a timestamp. the `booking_session` is the name of where the bookings are saved and the `bk_room` constains the number of the room.

So before a booking is commited i am trying to match the `new` booking date with old booking dates for the same room and then show an error message.

Update

new error, seems is returning too many rows how can i do one at a time.

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "U1146815.DOUBLE_BOOKINGS", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'U1146815.DOUBLE_BOOKINGS'
```

Answer (score 0):

You apparently have another trigger called `ROOM_BOOKED` on the `BOOKING_SESSION` table. And that trigger is in an invalid (uncompiled) state.

If you simply want to prevent records with duplicate bk_room/start_session values, just add a unique constraint to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE booking_session
add CONSTRAINT my_constraint UNIQUE (bk_room, start_session);
```

EDIT: Your new error is because you multiple records with the same bk_room value in the table, which would be expected. But, as I state above, you do not need a trigger to prevent duplicates, just a unique constraint.

Comment: that b a good idea, however i still need to create a trigger as i am being asked to. it seems i need to create a cursor to process a row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `SELECT...INTO` in your code, then the select must return EXACTLY one row. In other case it throws NO_DATA_FOUND exception or TOO_MANY_ROWS (your case). You can catch these exceptions, but it can make the code unclear. Better use cursor to query your record.

try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DOUBLE_BOOKINGS
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON BOOKING_SESSION
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    session_date TIMESTAMP;
    session_room NUMBER;
    CURSOR c_existing IS
        SELECT start_session
            FROM booking_session
        WHERE bk_room = :NEW.bk_room and
              session_date = :NEW.start_session;
    dummy_session c_existing.start_session%TYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_existing;
    FETCH c_existing INTO dummy_session;
    IF c_existing%FOUND THEN
       CLOSE c_existing;
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR
          (-1000, 'Room is already booked');
    END IF;
    CLOSE c_existing;
END;
```

/